# How do I make sure an array is equal in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I'm testing a website's dropdown menu to sort by Names.

```
$nameSort = array();
    $numOfNames = $this->getXpathCount("//td[@class='entry']");
    for($count = 1; $count <= $numOfNames; $count ++) {
        $get = $this->getText("xpath=(//td/a[contains(@href, '')])[$count]");
        array_push($nameSort, $get);
    }
    $test = sort($entrySort);
    $this->assertEquals($entrySort, $test);
```

But it says "There was 1 failure:

`NameTest::testNameTab true does not match expected type "array".`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `sort` returns a boolean and sorts the array in place.

As an example:

```
$arr = array(1,5,3); 
var_dump(sort($arr)); 
var_dump($arr);
```

That will result in this:

```
bool(true)
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(5)
}
```

You probably want this (or something like it):

```
sort($nameSort);
$this->assertEquals($entrySort, $nameSort);
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know whats the difference between sort($nameSort) and giving it a variable, $test = sort($nameSort);